# If my build targets iOS 5.0, what happens when older OS versions try to download/run it?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I recently submitted an app to the app store. My iOS version target is 5.0.

What will happen when users with older iOS versions try download my app?

Comment: I don't think the app will show up in the App Store for them at all.

Comment: They do show up, and @Coolant is right. 1st Gen iPod Touch iOS 3.1.3 FTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users of an older iOS try to buy/install it they will get an alert that says they need iOS5 to run this app....and not be able to purchase

Answer (score 2):

If users download it from iTunes on their computer, it will download but they won't be able to sync it to their iDevices. But if they try to download it directly from their iDevice, the device will pop up an alert, saying that they won't be able to download it.

But, most app right now has lower iOS version target for broader audience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually test this, you can change the target build for your app and run it in a simulator/test phone to see what happens.

If there is anything that is in your iPhone app that is iOS 5 only, there should be some problems. ARC and weak references are compatible with iOS 4.x, but not iOS 3.x.

EDIT: Make sure that the minimum OS required is not also set to iOS 5, because then it will not run on any lower OS version.